# Getting files in directory(directory has numbers in directory name)in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get files from directory (which has numbers in directory name). I am using below script. But it is throwing error.

```
yesterday=140402
os.chdir("C:\pythonPrograms\04-03-2014")
for file in glob.glob("MY*"+str(yesterday)+".log"):
    print file
```

Error received:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\pythonPrograms\x04-03-2014'
```

Do I need to follow some convention while giving the path? The code works fine if I search in `C:\pythonPrograms`

Comment: just use forward slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"C:\pythonPrograms\04-03-2014"
```

The issue is the "\04", the \ character is used to denote an escape character, you may know about \n for new line. You can fix this by just doing:

```
os.chdir(r"C:\pythonPrograms\04-03-2014")
```

Which makes the string into a raw string. Or you can add another escape character to escape the escape character like:

```
"C:\\pythonPrograms\\04-03-2014"
```